# Update a Wordpress post or page takes 60+ seconds

Tags: mysql

Since updating to Wordpress 3.5 I've had my updates of pages and posts become excessively slow. I've been timing them and they take 40-80 seconds to update.

I've spent the last 2 hours reading and trying everything I can find in the Wordpress.org forums yet nothing works.

I use maxcdn and CloudFlare for the frontside but the backside is unbearable.

I am on a MU install using 3.5.2 and I have disabled and tested each plugin. Seems to be a Wordpress issue and I'm looking for a workaround.

I'm on dual core VPS with 3GB of ram.

Comment: hey gabearnold, how far have you gone with that? Have you found where is the bottleneck? Is it your Server(Apache/Nginx), your database, your application? what do the logs say?

Comment: It's apache. I am looking in the logs and TOP in MySQL and nothing glaring stands out...

Comment: To get sure the problem is not with your MYSQL you can run SHOW PROCESSLIST; when trying to insert a new post and see if there is any query taking longer then it should. Or rather, turn on your slow_query_log... ;-)

Comment: It's not taking *quite* as long as you're reporting, but I've seen a definite (albeit anecdotal) slowness on the backend since updating as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a plugin called Debug Bar which you can find at http://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/  Don't leave this enabled in production! But it will tattle on slow MySQL queries.

You might also wish to try using WP Clean Up.  http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clean-up/  This flushes out stale entries in your database, and does a little bit of table reorg/optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing today. It turned out that WP Maintenance Mode plugin slowed down my website. After I deactivated the plugin, all was good again.

Maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Nine years on, further investigation of this slowdown on post and page updates shows that sites with lots of users are inefficient. It's the dropdown list of potential authors that causes the problem.  The fix is to stop using MySQL queries that look like this

```
WHERE ... wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'
     AND  wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%"editor"%'
```

in favor of queries that look like this

```
WHERE ... wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_iufsr:editor'
```

Rigging that up is a little tricky, but I've made a free GPL plugin for the purpose. [Index WP Users For Speed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-users-for-speed/).